# HttpUnit and jQuery: EcmaError

Tags: java, jquery, unit-testing, http-unit

Currently I'm developing unit tests for j2ee application.
It uses jQuery version 1.4.

And when I'm trying to click the link and go the next web page(in java test code), HttpUnit fails with exception:

```
org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot find function createElement in object [object Document]. (httpunit#916)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3654)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3632)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3660)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3679)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFunctionError(ScriptRuntime.java:3743)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThisHelper(ScriptRuntime.java:2247)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThis(ScriptRuntime.java:2214)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:3143)
    at script(httpunit:916)
    at script(httpunit:912)
    at script(httpunit:15)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:2487)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:164)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:398)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3065)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:175)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.evaluateString(Context.java:1104)
    at com.meterware.httpunit.javascript.ScriptingEngineImpl.runScript(ScriptingEngineImpl.java:92)
    at com.meterware.httpunit.scripting.ScriptableDelegate.runScript(ScriptableDelegate.java:88)
    at com.meterware.httpunit.ParsedHTML.interpretScriptElement(ParsedHTML.java:364)
    at com.meterware.httpunit.ParsedHTML$ScriptFactory.recordElement(ParsedHTML.java:533)
    at com.meterware.httpunit.ParsedHTML$2.processElement(ParsedHTML.java:744)
    at com.meterware.httpunit.NodeUtils$PreOrderTraversal.perform(NodeUtils.java:241)
    at com.meterware.httpunit.ParsedHTML.loadElements(ParsedHTML.java:760)
    at com.meterware.httpunit.ParsedHTML.getFrames(ParsedHTML.java:1101)
    at com.meterware.httpunit.WebResponse.getFrames(WebResponse.java:1285)
    at com.meterware.httpunit.WebResponse.getFrameRequests(WebResponse.java:1024)
    at com.meterware.httpunit.FrameHolder.updateFrames(FrameHolder.java:179)
    at com.meterware.httpunit.WebWindow.updateFrameContents(WebWindow.java:315)
    at com.meterware.httpunit.WebClient.updateFrameContents(WebClient.java:526)
    at com.meterware.httpunit.WebWindow.updateWindow(WebWindow.java:201)
    at com.meterware.httpunit.WebWindow.getSubframeResponse(WebWindow.java:183)
    at com.meterware.httpunit.WebWindow.getResponse(WebWindow.java:158)
    at com.meterware.httpunit.WebWindow.sendRequest(WebWindow.java:134)
    at com.meterware.httpunit.WebResponse.submitRequest(WebResponse.java:742)
    at com.meterware.httpunit.dom.DomWindow.submitRequest(DomWindow.java:181)
    at com.meterware.httpunit.dom.HTMLAnchorElementImpl.doClickAction(HTMLAnchorElementImpl.java:183)
    at com.meterware.httpunit.WebLink.click(WebLink.java:96)
    at mycompany.testcase.pages.WelcomePage.goToFilterPage(WelcomePage.java:30)
    at mycompany.testcase.DownloadReportTest.testReportDownload(DownloadReportTest.java:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:168)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:113)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:243)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:238)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:243)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:238)
    at mycompany.App.main(App.java:29)
```

Does anybody knows any workaround to avoid this error ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I've found is to refuse using HttpUnit and choose between [jWebUnit](http://jwebunit.sourceforge.net/) and [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Swapping to HtmlUnit achieve the wanted result for me

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround I would recomment disabling Javascript:

```
HttpUnitOptions.setScriptingEnabled(false);
```

Comment: If he's testing his application that uses JavaScript then why would he disable it?